# Drawables in disabled TextViews

Tags: android, android-layout

I have TextViews in my layout. Depending on some checkboxes they might be disabled. When they are disabled, their text color is lighter. Is there a way to make the drawable in the TextView lighter too, or to apply a different drawable (preferably in XML, I know how to change it in the code)?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_disable" android:state_enabled="false"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_normal"/>

    </selector>
```

set that as the background of your textview instead of just the drawable

Answer (score 0):

`Drawable.setAlpha()` sets the opacity of the drawable, you might want to do something like:

```
// When the checkbox is selected
int alpha = 63; // Change the best value to fit your need
drawable.setAlpha(alpha);
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see you've already known how to do it in .java, just ignore this post

Answer (score 0):

Starting with minSdkVersion=23 drawableTint can be initialized with the selector in xml. For example:

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableEnd="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        app:drawableTint="@color/drawabe_tint_selector" />
```

Selector, put it into res/color/drawabe_tint_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
  <item android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>
</selector>
```